# Simple R while loop not working

Tags: r

```
count <- 0
while(count < 10) {
  print(count)
  count <- count + 1 
}
```

While running the above code, I am just getting 3 empty lines.

```
>
>
>
```

Comment: you should at least add a tag of what language that is

Comment: I did add a tag. Its R language.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Start a clean R session?

Comment: I cannot replicate. Are you sure you didn't reassign a function to `print` in your current environment? Have you tried restarting R to clear out any potential conflicts?

Comment: Yes I restarted the session. Its behaving the same. And no, I didn't reassign any new function to print. Am using R 3.1

Comment: look in search() for a wierd print() or while()?

Comment: [IMG]http://i57.tinypic.com/2wc2rur.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: sorry! i did not see that tag! my bad, didn't realize r was a language...

Comment: @MrFlick. I had made a script file of the above code. Is that the wrong way? Its working fine otherwise.

Comment: @HarishVishwakarma So how are you running this? `source()`? Because I don't see the code in your console in the screen shot. I do see a "restored R session" which means you didn't exactly do a "clean" restart (not sure how you do this in Rstudio because I don't use it).

Comment: @MrFlick: Did you see the While.R file opened above the console? I just clicked the Run button on the top right corner of that window.

Comment: @HarishVishwakarma Are you new to Rstudio? Doesn't "Run" just run the current line? The commands should be appearing the the bottom console when they actually run.

Comment: Yes I am new to Rstudio. I get it now. I selected the entire code in the script file and ran it. It worked fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out above, you weren't running the code you thought you were. When you press "Run" in R-Studio, it only runs the current line, not the entire code block in the active window. You can either repeatedly press Run, or highly a black of text and press Run. That should send commands to the Console window where they are executed.

So the code you wrote was fine, the problem was just in how you were running it.